# 0 connected nodes in datastax opscenter

Tags: cassandra

Installed opscenterd on the separate node outside of the cluster, but within firewall ( aws security group ). Tested all possible ports between agents and opcenter server. No errors in the log..

```
2013-10-30 01:07:23+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Initializing event storage.
2013-10-30 01:07:23+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Attempting to load all persisted alert rules
2013-10-30 01:07:23+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Done loading persisted alert rules
2013-10-30 01:07:23+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Done initializing event storage.
2013-10-30 01:07:23+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Done loading persisted scheduled job descriptions
2013-10-30 01:07:23+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2013-10-30 01:07:23+0000 []  INFO: Finished starting new cluster services for FC_Cluster
2013-10-30 01:08:04+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Agent for ip 10.34.10.185 is version u'3.2.2'
2013-10-30 01:08:04+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Agent for ip 10.32.37.251 is version u'3.2.2'
2013-10-30 01:08:04+0000 [FC_Cluster]  INFO: Agent for ip 10.82.226.252 is version u'3.2.2'
```

The most interesting part that I can see some data in the opscenter UI, when I stop agents, there is no data displayed, when I start - it show up again, but at the same time it shows 0 connected nodes. Storage capacity is even funnier - 3 of 0 nodes..

[image]

Any ideas why that could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The push/stomp connection between the browser and opscenterd is broken.  You can see this by the disconnected plug icon near the top right.

Assuming you're still using [nginx proxying](https://serverfault.com/questions/549249/how-to-run-datastax-opscenter-behind-nginx), try turning proxy_buffering off.  Other users have had success with this in the past.

Comment: Man, I'll buy you a beer! Saved me so many times.